# Creating a custom forum, help with building a query that counts posts in a categories etc

Tags: mysql, database

So my database setup is fairly simple.

I have a `forum_cat` table (a forum category) and `forum_post` table.

The `forum_post` has a field `fk_forum_cat_id` which ties each forum post to a category.

Each `forum_post` also has a field `fk_parent_forum_post_id` which basically says it belongs to an original post.

Further more, there is a `date_added` and `date_edited` field in forum_post.

Now, I am trying to generate the front page for my forum.  I want to show a list of forum categories.  Each one category should have a post count and the latest post.  Could someone give me some direction with a query that does that all in one.  I don't want to run 20 separate queries!

Comment: How do we determine the latest post? Is there a date column? Is fk_parent_forum_post_id an auto-incremented integer field?

Comment: there is a date_posted and date_edited field in forum_post

Comment: does it have to be one query?  its a whole lot easier if you split it into two... one to get the cat id's (or names), their count, and their max post date, and the other to get the actual post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you are seeking the category, the count of posts in the category, and the latest post in that category. Perhaps this simplification of laurent-rpnet's answer will do the trick...

```
SELECT c.forum_cat_id,
       COUNT(p.fk_forum_cat_id),
       MAX(p.date_added), 
      (SELECT p2.post_title
           FROM forum_post AS p2 
           WHERE p2.forum_cat_id = c.forum_cat_id
           ORDER BY date_added DESC
           LIMIT 1)
    FROM forum_cat AS c INNER JOIN 
               forum_post AS p ON p.fk_forum_cat_id = c.forum_cat_id
    GROUP BY c.forum_cat_id;
```

Comment: Good point +1! I was seeking something like that but couldn't imagine it. The `Order bY date...Limit 1` will happily substitute my subquery, probably be faster and without depending on the autoincremented id.

Answer (score 1):

If `forum_post` primary key is auto-incremented (should be but we never know...), this will return what you need:

```
SELECT c.forum_cat_id, COUNT(p.fk_forum_cat_id), MAX(p.date_added), 
    (SELECT p2.post_title FROM forum_post AS p2 
        WHERE p2.forum_post_id = (SELECT MAX(p3.forum_post_id) FROM forum_post AS p3 
            WHERE p3.fk_forum_cat_id = p2.fk_forum_cat_id) AND p2.fk_forum_cat_id = c.forum_cat_id) 
FROM forum_cat AS c INNER JOIN 
    forum_post AS p ON p.fk_forum_cat_id = c.forum_cat_id
GROUP BY c.forum_cat_id;
```

I had to guess some field names:

- `forum_cat_id` = `forum _cat` primary key
- `forum_post_id` = `forum_post` primary key
- `post_title` = post title or begining of post text in `forum_post` (depends on what you want to show).
- The `COUNT(p.fk_forum_cat_id)` column will contain the post count in category

In addition to what you asked, you will get the date of the lastest post in the category as I think you'll need it if it is a good forum ;).

Obs: I didn't test it so you may need some debugging. If you have problems, let me know.

Comment: You can use `date_edited` instead of `date_added` if you prefer

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this example to your problem:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `test_post` AS p3
JOIN (

SELECT MAX( id ) AS id
FROM  `test_post` AS p1
JOIN (

SELECT MAX(  `test_post`.date ) AS DATE, cat
FROM  `test_post` 
GROUP BY cat
) AS p2 ON p1.date = p2.date
AND p1.cat = p2.cat
GROUP BY p1.cat
) AS p4 ON p3.id = p4.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Queries to dynamically count things tend to get slow very quickly and consume a lot of cpu.  Even with good indexes, MySQL has to do a lot of work every single time to count all those rows.

An alternative to a query like this would be to summarize the counts of posts in the `forum_cat` table.  Create a column named something like `posts_count`.  Every time a post is created, it's easy enough to run a query increment or decrement the count.

> UPDATE forum_cat SET posts_count=posts_count+1;

When you go to create the front page, your query becomes much more simple, and performant.

Comment: True! Count is slow but finding the last post in each cat is the hard job for this query. Keeping only post counts in `forum_cat` won't help in this part. If going this way, I think you should keep also last `post_id` and the query will be a lot simpler/faster. This depends on forum size but I believe the number of cats should stay reasonable and the query will perform quickly. Chris Henry proposal (adding last `post_id`) could be implemented using Delete and Insert triggers and a maintenance query to correct the values when (not if) something goes wrong and the values are not correct.